# С# TextBox WindowsForm

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток, подскажите как присвоить переменной значение записанное мною в `textbox`

Comment: Зачем задавать вопрос, который легко посмотреть в MSDN
TextBox.Text

Comment: `var txt = TextBox.text`?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что так:

```
string tb = textbox.text;
```